# Check parents elements contain a specific CSS class by only using javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I click on any DOM element I want to check if its parents element contains a specific class or not. I am trying in this way but can't achieve this goal. Does anyone know how?

```
document.onclick=function(e){
    console.log(e.parentElement('.drop').id);       
}
```

Please give solution in JavaScript only - I can't use jQuery.

Comment: The class is found in the "className" property.

Comment: Are you checking the direct parent, or all parents?

Comment: If you want to check all ancestors: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16863917

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `classList` property of the parent element. It has a `contains()` method that is useful for your purpose:

```
document.onclick=function(e){
    console.log( e.parentElement.classList.contains( 'drop' ) );       
}
```

If you are targeting Internet Explorer, (IE<10), you can manually parse the list of classes and look for 'drop' in them:

```
document.onclick=function(e){
    console.log( e.parentElement.className.split(' ').indexOf('button-panel')!==-1 );
}
```

`split()` parses the className to multiple names in an array.
`indexOf()` searches for an element in an array, if it can't find it, it returns -1

Comment: `classList` is only supported in IE from version 10. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added a new version of the code to eliminate this issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `console.parentElement` will be undefined.

Comment: i Think this is the right answer....................................................................................  ......................                document.onclick=function(e){
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains( 'drop' );       
}

Comment: @jbabey: thanks for pointing it out. It was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

the `e` passed to an event handler is the event object, not the element that was clicked. Try grabbing the `srcElement`, then it's parent's `className`. Also, since you can't use jQuery, passing selectors like `.drop` around won't do anything but cause syntax errors.

```
document.onclick = function(e){
    console.log(e.srcElement.parentNode.className);

    e.stopPropagation(); // don't bubble
};
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7WTkk/)

Comment: Please comment when you downvote so the answer can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

```
now i got the answer 

document.onclick=function(e){   
    if (!e) e = window.event;
        curDD = findparentClass(e.target.parentNode,'drop');
        console.log(curDD);
    }
}
function findparentClass(node, clsName) {           
    if(node.className != clsName && node.className!=null){
        return findparentClass(node.parentNode,clsName);                    
    }else if(node.className!=null){
        return true;    
    }
}
```

where 'drop' is a class which you want to search...

Answer (score 0):

For new people who are searching for this use below code.

```js
function findparentClass(node, clsName) {
    if (node && !node.className) {
        return findparentClass(node.parentNode, clsName);
    } else if(node && node.className){
        if(!node.classList.contains(clsName)){
            return findparentClass(node.parentNode, clsName);
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Simply send in the e.target element and the className you are looking for. If there present any parent with the className then the function will return true, othertimes it will retun undefined.

So, use it like,

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log(findparentClass(e.target, 'targetClassName'));

})
```