# How can I test if an ancestor of my HTML element has a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, jasmine, css-selectors

Given HTML code like so -

```
<div id="parent" class="foo">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I write a test to see if the `child` element has the class `foo` applied? I tried:

```
element
.children("#child") //successfully selects child
.hasClass("foo");   //false :(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS classes don't trickle down like that, but you can still check if an ancestor has the class like this:

[Check if any ancestor has a class using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084839/check-if-any-ancestor-has-a-class-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your `#child` does not have a `foo` class. The `parent` has it, right?!

PS. David, seems like you had enough for today :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes don't work that way.  They only apply to the element on which they are applied and should not affect the children explicitly like that.

Comment: Thats not exactly true though, is it? Specifically, in my example if the parent has an `ng-hide`, then the child is also hidden.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Well as i understand it, that is calculated after the fact. so the child class doesn't explicitly have that class. and so .hasClass will fail

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Kinda! Classes aren't inherited, but some attributes applied by them are, like `color`.  ng-hide applies `display:none` which is a bit of a special case - since the parent's box isn't present anymore, the children can't really be there either. But for example if you had a class that applied the `border` property, its children wouldn't inherit the border.

Answer (score 0):

Neither CSS or jQuery can do that. One suggestion is using `closest`.

```
$(function(){
  var element = $('#parent').children('#child');
  if (element.closest('.foo').length > 0) {
    //you will get true for .foo, #child, or #parent, or div, ...
    console.log('Yay!');
  } else {
    console.log('Duh!');
  }
});
```

Prints 'Yay!'.

That method will check if the element or an ancestor have the class you need. You can ask for a class or for an ID. If you want to check for hidden -as you said- elements, you can try the `:hidden` pseudoselector in the regular `is` call, rather than `hasClass` ([Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/86q6xexd/2/)):

```
<div id="parent" class="foo" style='display: none'>
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>

$(function(){
  var element = $('#parent').children('#child');
  if (element.is(':hidden')) {
    console.log('Yay!');
  } else {
    console.log('Duh!');
  }
});
```

Prints 'Yay!'.

Another one is this, given your current DOM ([Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/86q6xexd/4/)):

```
$(function(){
  var element = $('#parent').children('#child');
  if (element.is('.foo *')) {
    console.log('Yay!');
  } else {
    console.log('Duh!');
  }
});
```

Prints 'Yay!'.

However you're using `ng-hide`, which usually means AngularJS. Don't know what is your intention but if you are not creating a custom directive please avoid using jquery and rethink your problem.

Answer (score 0):

## With jQuery

How to check with jQuery if any ancestor of an element has a class named `foo` :

```
$element.parents('.foo').length > 0
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var $element = $('#child');

alert(
    $element.parents('.foo').length > 0
);

alert(
    $element.parents('.bar').length > 0
);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" class="foo">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vsavL7bf/))

---

## Without jQuery

How to check without jQuery if any ancestor of an element has a class named `foo` :

```
element.matches('.foo ' + element.tagName)
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var element = document.getElementById('child');

alert(
    element.matches('.foo ' + element.tagName)
);

alert(
    element.matches('.bar ' + element.tagName)
);
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="foo">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cwe6oh9f/))

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.children()` the selector has moved on to another DOM node. To traverse back to the parent you can just use `.end()`, i.e.:

```
element
.children("#child")//successfully selects child
.end()//moves cursor back the parent element
.hasClass("foo");//true :)
```