# using jquery, accessing parent div and checking if it has a specific class

Tags: jquery, html

How would I access parent `div` and check if it has a specific class

```
<div class="current">
    <img src="aaa.jpg" class="me-child">
</div>
```

with jquery clicking on the `div` and using `this` keyword, I want to know if parent `div` has the class of `current`

thanks

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. `:(`

Comment: `if($(this).closest('div').hasClass('current'))` OR `if($(this).parent().hasClass('current'))`

Comment: And here you go ^...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if any ancestor has a class using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084839/check-if-any-ancestor-has-a-class-using-jquery)

Comment: @KiranJoshi who would use the search word ancestor? I would have never found that (-:

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).parent().hasClass("current")) return true;
```