# How to select elements those have certain two ancestors?

Tags: jquery

I would like to select all elements those have

1. an ancestor with class X, and
2. an ancestor with id Y.

By some reason. I need to use 'on' method of jquery
So  please tell me an string which I can use with 'on' method

Comment: can you please update your question with an example code.

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if any ancestor has a class using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084839/check-if-any-ancestor-has-a-class-using-jquery)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Leb9yrs/) example

your html

```
<div class="container">

  <button class="check">
     check
  </button>

  <div id="y">
    <div class="x">
      test1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="p">
    <div class="x">
      test2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="y">
    <div class="p">
      test3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="y">
    <div class="x">
      test4
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

your JavaScript function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".check").click(function() {
    $('[id=y]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).find(".x").length > 0) {
        alert($(this).text());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Result**

test1

test4