# Efficient check for a CSS class in any of the parents of a DOM node

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking for an efficient way to check if any of the parents of a DOM node has a given CSS class.

My question is very similar to this one:
[Check if class exists somewhere in parent - vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863917/check-if-class-exists-somewhere-in-parent-vanilla-js), except that I am explicitly looking for advice on how to implement this in the most efficient way (this code will be called very often).

The accepted answer to the above question suggests a recursive solution. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Do you know any information about the class? For example, if the class you're looking for is `foo`, is it possible there is a class `food` as well? Are we assuming it's totally generic?

Comment: A generic solution would be better but I have control over class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like a nice syntax, use the [`matchesSelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches) method ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/matchesselector)).

This method has undergone some name changes, and it's still prefixed, so to use it, normalize the name:

```
var matchesSelector;
['webkitM', 'mozM', 'msM', 'oM', 'm'].some(function(prefix) {
    var name = prefix + 'atches';
    if (name in document.documentElement) {
        matchesSelector = name;
    }
    name += 'Selector';
    if (name in document.documentElement) {
        matchesSelector = name;
    }
    return matchesSelector; // If found, then truthy, and [].some() ends.
});
```

After determining the name, you can use it as follows:

```
// Usage
element[matchesSelector]('.someclass *');
```

Or just extend the prototype:

```
Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype[matchesSelector];
// Usage
element.matches('.someclass *');
```

Comment: This looks good. Do you have any information about performance of this? I would like to know if this is expected to be faster/slower than traversing the DOM hierarchy up by using `el.parentNode`

Comment: @Grodriguez `matches` / `matchesSelector` appears to be faster than traversing the tree, regardless of the tree's height. See these two benchmarks: http://jsperf.com/matchesselector-vs-traversal-classlist-classname and http://jsperf.com/matchesselector-vs-traversal-classlist-classname-small

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
var hasClass = (function() {
    var hasClassList = !!document.documentElement.classList;

    return function(dom, cls) {
        var spaced = ' ' + cls + ' ';
        while (dom.parentNode) {
            if (hasClassList) {
                if (dom.classList.contains(cls)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                if ((' ' + dom.className + ' ').indexOf(spaced) !== -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            dom = dom.parentNode;
        }
        return false;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Ehm, how is this faster than the original answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16863971/450398) ?

Comment: A few reasons. It uses classList where available. It doesn't use recursion so there's no extra function call overhead. It doesn't use split every time to convert it to an array.

Comment: OK. Marginally faster I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parentIsOfClass = ($("[DOM ID or CLASS]").parents().filter("[PARENT CLASS]").length > 0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Will return true or false

Comment: jQuery is almost always going to be slower than a vanilla JavaScript solution.

Comment: This is by way much slower than the solution to the SO question that I linked to, as it needs to retrieve all parents of the element, and then filter them.