# Vanilla javascript check if element or ancestor has class

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello this code gets tells me if current element has class.

```
e.srcElement.className.indexOf('thisClass') === 0
```

How do i also check if element or any of its parents have the class?

Comment: Where are the `ancestor` elements ? Please provide HTML as well..

Comment: ancestor elements don't matter, it could have infinity divs wrapped around it

Comment: Question seems incomplete to me. A proper `markup` would give us more idea about the post..

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16863917

Answer (score 14):

Nowadays one can use the widely supported JavaScript [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method.

```
const parentHasClass = element.closest('.thisClass');
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the [parentNode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) of an element, it's possible to go through the parents list.
Use the following function:

```
function elementOrAncestorHasClass(element, className) {
  if (!element || element.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  var parent = element;
  do {
    if (parent === document) {
      break;
    }
    if (parent.className.indexOf(className) >= 0) {
      return true;
    }
  } while (parent = parent.parentNode);
  return false;
}
```

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4jnL9cw/) shows the function in action.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to traverse the DOM. To go one parent up, use [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

Do traverse infinitely upwards, you'll need to use a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  // check if each parentNode has the class
}
```

It's a tedious process. That's why libraries like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) exist for the sole purpose of DOM traversal/manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer to use next methods:

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
    return !(!className || !element || !element.className 
    || !element.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')));
}

function parentByClass(childElement, className) {
    if (!childElement || childElement === document) {
        return null;
    } else if (hasClass(childElement, className)) {
        return childElement;
    } else {
        return parentByClass(childElement.parentNode, className)
    }
}

function hasClassInTree(element, className) {
    return hasClass(element, className) || parentByClass(element, className)
}
```

So in you case condition will be

```
if (hasClassInTree(e.srcElement, 'thisClass')) { ... }
```

Comment: I needed to put the `childElement === document` check before the `hasClass(childElement, className)` check otherwise it throws an error in `hasClass` because `document.className` is undefined. I have suggested an edit to your answer to fix this. Thanks for the function!

Comment: @JoeRocc Thank you, you are right! Let's make it more compact and secure =)

Answer (score -1):

May be its easier to find all the elements that have the class, and check if any of them contain the current node (not tested code):

```
   function checkParentClass(e,className){
      var nodesWithClass =document.getElementsByClassName("className");

      var index =0;
      var found = false;

      while(index< nodesWithClass.length && !found){
         if (nodesWithClass[index].contains(e))
         {
            found = true;
         }
         index++;
      }

      return found;
    }
```