# Event on created element

Tags: javascript, events

In my ***to-do-list deleteButton*** and ***doneButton*** work only on premade tasks.

They arent working on created elements li even that created elements are the same as premade. I am trying to use **vanila js**.

js:

```
var deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

for(i = 0; i < deleteButton.length; i++){
      deleteButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      var li = this.parentNode;
      li.classList.add('li-delete');
})
};

var doneButton = document.querySelectorAll('.done');
for (i = 0; i < doneButton.length; i++)

doneButton[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
   if (this.classList.contains('done-green')) {
      this.classList.remove('done-green');
   } else {
      this.classList.add('done-green');
   }
});

var add = document.querySelector('.add');

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
   var newLi = document.createElement('li');
   var input = document.querySelector('input');
   var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
   var newP = document.createElement('p');
   newLi.innerHTML = "<i class='icon-ok done'></i><i class='icon-trash delete'></i>"
   newP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
   newLi.appendChild(newP);
   ul.appendChild(newLi);
   input.value = null;
})
```

html:

```
<div id="buttons">
  <input type="text" placeholder="your new task...">
  <button type="submit" class="add">add</button> 
 </div>
 <div id="tasks">
    <ul>
       <li><i class="icon-ok done"></i>
       <p>asd</p>
       <i class="icon-trash delete"></i></li>
       <li><i class="icon-ok done"></i>
       <p>asd</p>
       <i class="icon-trash delete"></i></li>
       <li><i class="icon-ok done"></i>
       <p>asd</p>
       <i class="icon-trash delete"></i></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) - See pure js answer

Answer (score -1):

You must attach listener after creation element.
Or you can attach listener to parent container of elements.
I think this answer can help you [Attach event to dynamic elements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: I passed deleteButton and doneButton in add function. I dont know if that is the best solution but it works, thanks.