# On click event not firing the first time on dynamically added elements via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a ul element that gets populated with li elements via AJAX.
Then I need to do something when clicking on those li elements.
The funny thing is that it works the second time I click on the li element it but not the first time.

I've read every possible related question I could find on StackOverflow but I can't find the answer to my problem.

Here is an example of the AJAX code:

```
$('#university').on('keyup', function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: {
                "search": searchVal,
                "action": 'autoComplete',
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $(".univers-name-list").html("");
                var  dataItem=[];
                dataItem=data.data.items;
                if(dataItem){
                    dataItem.forEach(function(element,key) {
                        $(".univers-name-list").append('<li>'+element.name+'</li>')
                    });
                }
             }
    });
});
```

And here is the on click function (in the same file):

```
$('.univers-name-list').on('click', 'li', function(e){
    // Code here
    console.log('Helo'); // Doesn't run the first time.
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why does it only work when I click it for the second time?

---

Some more info:
When I checked the event target, the first time I click on any li element, the target is UL (populated with the dynamically added LI elements), but the second time is the correct LI element.

Comment: I think we need more detail here, in particular the contents of your click handler function.

Comment: even a console.log('helo') doesn't execute inside the click handler function.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/ficofanafi/1/edit?js,console,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's interesting. This snippet works. But not with real ajax. Any idea?

Comment: @Quentin I've tried your snippet in the document ready and it worked.
But as soon as I put it inside an on keyup callback it doesn't work. And that's what is actually firing up the ajax.I'll refresh my code.

Comment: @jstneti — You need to provide a [mcve]. Maybe this is just a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element). Maybe you aren't triggering the keyup event correctly.

Comment: @Quentin I was just trying to provide an example and it looks like it might be CSS related. By putting it outside of all the wrappers it's actually working ok. When I find the solution, I'll post it here in case it helps anyone else. Thanks for all the help and your time Quentin.

Comment: It's not CSS, it's JS. A custom jquery validation rule on the input field that I somehow missed yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a custom validation rule on the input field that messed up everything.
After fixing that rule, it now works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Event listeners will not work fFor elements created dynamically via javascript.

You have to use delegate functions for these kind of elements

**This code should work fine on you element created dynamically.**

```
$(document).on('click', '.univers-name-list li', function(e){
    // Code here
    console.log('Helo');
});
```

Comment: That is, more or less, what they are doing already. They're just binding to `.univers-name-list` (which is in the document) and not `document`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to call addEventListener to the new created elements. 
check this [Attach event to dynamic elements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: No, they don't. They are using event delegation.