# function for all span elements - changing color on clicks

Tags: function, appendchild, multiplication, pure-js

I have a problem, I want to make clickable boxes (span class="label") like this:

- first click = changing background to red,
- second click = background change to blue,
- third click = no color.

However, counting a click is not on each box separately, only globally. For example, first click on box number 1 and we have a red color (this is OK), but the second click on box number X appears blue, but should be counted as the first click on this box.

The second problem is that after pressing the button "new task", the new boxes are no longer attached to the function changeColor().

```
My codepen: `https://codepen.io/klaudiabudzisch/pen/QooOXV `
```

My code:

```
<section class="daily-task">
<!-------- title -------->
  <div class="header one">
    <button id="addDaily">new task</button>
    <h1>Daily Tasks</h1>
  </div>

<!-------- tasks -------->

  <div id="daily" class="task">
        <div class="task-text">
                <input type="text" class="text">
        </div>
        <div class="box-numbers">
                <span class="label">1</span>
                <span class="label">2</span>
                <span class="label">3</span>
                <span class="label">4</span>
                <span class="label">5</span>
                <span class="label">6</span>
                <span class="label">7</span>
                <span class="label">8</span>
                <span class="label">9</span>
                <span class="label">10</span>
        </div>
  </div>
</section>


 **CODE JS** 


const dailyBtn = document.getElementById("addDaily");

dailyBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const boxes = document.getElementById("daily");
  const clone = boxes.cloneNode(true);
  boxes.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
 });


 let box = document.querySelectorAll("span.label");
 let clicks = 0;

 Array.from(box).forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
});

function changeColor() {
    clicks++;
  if (clicks == 1) {
    this.style.backgroundColor ='red';
} if (clicks == 2) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
} if (clicks == 3) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
} if (clicks == 4) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = '';
  clicks = 0;
}
}
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? Is what I wrote correct at all?

Comment: Please share all relevant parts of your code here, not anywhere else

Comment: ok, code added :)

Comment: So, that's simple: you count the number of clicks globally. Better store the counter per element, for example through a custom attribute on the clicked element

Comment: shoud I replace "clicks++;" to "e.dataset.clicks++;"  before if statement?

Comment: Well, you need to use some kind of variable to read and write that data, `e.dataset` sounds good

Comment: @NicoHaase Okay, I fixed this and works :) But still, I have problem with added new elements. What should I do to make them active on this clicks?

Comment: Good to know that you've come a step closer to the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript will help you about new elements

Comment: Now, all is clear for me. Thank you!