# Reusing ajax call results on jQuery click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The task is to fetch some data from pokemon api and append it to the list. **Api request results have links on previous and next pages.**

HTML:

```
<ul class="poke-list"></ul>
<div class="pagination">
   <button class="prev">Prev</button>
   <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

here's a function that makes an api call (async await is necessary):

```
var getData = async function (url, pokemonName) {
   var response;

   if(!pokemonName) {
     response = await $.get(url);
   } else {
     response = await $.get(url + pokemonName);
   }
     return response;
};
```

A function to append content and handle click events:

```
var appendContent = function (data) {
  var list = $('.poke-list');
   list.empty();

   var res = data;
   var pokemons = res.results;
   pokemons.forEach(function (item) {
     list.append($(`<li>${item.name}</li>`));
  $('.prev').on('click', function (event) {
    res = data;
    var url2 = res.previous;
    if (url2 === undefined || url2 === null) {
      alert('Limit reached!');
    } else {
       getData(url2)
        .then(appendContent);
    }
   });

  $('.next').on('click', function (event) {
     res = data;
     var url = res.next;
     if (url === undefined || url ===null) {
        alert('Limit reached!');
     } else {
        getData(url)
          .then(appendContent)
  });

});
```

I call it on page load (yes it is necessary):

```
$(function {
  getData()
    .then(appendcontent)
```

here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aikast/4rgcvd7z/

What happens is that every time append function is called it creates new click events (I know that's how it should work), and the code stops working properly (it does not see **current** ajax call results, so every value is null).

Stopping event propagation did not help.

Is there a way to organise it differently? I can't find a way for c**lick event handlers to see ajax call results outside of appendContent function scope**

***The question was marked duplicate, but buttons are static, they are not dynamically added!***

Comment: The main problem is that you keep adding event listeners to the two buttons, which means when you click prev/next the first time, it works fine, but clicking any of them again will run the click handler twice, then thrice, etc. Also, you need `then(appendcontent)` in your page load code.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what my problem is, but I need those api call results in click event handlers, so they must be in a function that gets/sees those results, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach event to dynamic elements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: buttons are not dinamically added! please re-read

Comment: I have no need in click events for dynamic content!

Comment: The solution is to use external variables that are *set* after the API data is received and *used* when a button is clicked. Which means this question is most definitely a duplicate, just not of the ones people thought it was. Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/myo8qtve/ (note that `var = function() { ...};` is a bad style because that way the function isn't hoisted)

Comment: yeah, I would be glad if it was marked duplicate by a correct link
you saved the day!

Comment: so the best way to add functions is through function declaration, not through function expressions right?

Comment: Declaring a variable external to make it available to more than one function is a basic programming concept. Finding a duplicate is not easy because if you take your own question as example, people are usually asking a very different thing. Anyway, yes, you shouldn't declare functions as `var`s.

Comment: This probably comes closest: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try something like below.
now only once click event fired.

```
$(next).unbind( "click" );
```

so every time when your function call, first it will unbind previous event.

you can check live demo as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/zhna7ksu/

---

`.unbind()` is deprecated and you should use the `.off()` method instead. Simply call `.off()` right before you call `.on()`

```
$(next).off().on("click", .......);
```

Comment: While this will work, it ignores the actual problem (which is about variable scope, not click handling)

Comment: can you explain, what is the problem in above solution?

Comment: The problem is that it completely ignores the bigger picture. Assigning (and therefore unbinding) a click handler after each API request is not necessary in the first place. If your bed is getting dirty from your shoes, the solution isn't to put plastic bags over your shoes ;)

Comment: @ChrisG why don't you take of your shoes. in other words why are you binding event in appendContent (take it out from there).

Comment: @Ejaz47 I'm not the OP; I already provided a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/myo8qtve/) that does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

store data/res (why double naming the same variable?) somewhere outside `appendData` (`window.pokemonResponse` for example) function context and declare `previous` and `next` logic outside `appendData`. Also, use `let` instead of `var`, even IE 11 supports let