# How tho check if button was clicked inside function onClick?

Tags: javascript

I have a marker that when that marker is clicked a model appears. Inside that model I have 3 buttons with 3 different functions. Inside the function onClick (of the marker) I wan't to check which of the tree button inside the model where clicked. SOmething along the lines of

```
if(('#button').isclicked == true)
 {
     aceite();
 }
```

It's important to note that my buttons are hidden and they're added by another function using append.

variables:

```
  var aceite = document.getElementById("aceite");
   var recusado = document.getElementById("recusado");
   var concluido = document.getElementById("concluido");
```

Here is the function that adds the buttons:

```
function getData(id) {

    $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`, function (data) {

        //o div terá que ser limpo para que a informação não seja subreposta
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = "";

        //Indicação do id e do estado da ignição clicada 
        $('#myDiv').append('<h3><b>Avaliação da Ignição</b></h3>');
        $('#myDiv').append('<p>Estado:' + data.estado + '</p>')
        $('#myDiv').append('<p>ID: ' + id + '</p>');

        $.each(data.listaOcorrencias, function (o, ocorrencia) {
            //é adicionado as imagens correspondente a cada ocorrencia pertecentes á ignição clicada
            $('#myDiv').append('<img src="imagensFogos/' + ocorrencia.fotografia + '" onclick="openModal();" class="hover-shadow" style="width:200px; height:190px" hspace="4"/>');

        });

        //adição dos botões que alteram o estado da ignição
        $('#buttons').append('<button id="aceite" style="background-color:#4CAF50;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); margin:5px;">Aceitar</button>');
        $('#buttons').append('<button id="recusado" style="background-color:#f44336;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);margin:5px;">Recusar</button>');
        $('#buttons').append('<button id="concluido"  style="background-color:#008CBA;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);margin:5px;" > Concluído</button>');

    });
}
```

Here is the piece of code where I want to check which button was clicked:

```
          $.get("/api/IgnicoesAPI", function (data) {



        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {

        //More Code

        var marker = new L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude], { icon: ignicao })

            .on('click', function onClick(e) {

                var id = item.id;

                clickedmarker = e.target;

                 if(aceite.isclicked == true)
                 {
                     //calls function
                 }
                  //Same for the other two buttons

              modal.style.display = "block";

                getData(id);
            }).addTo(map);







            //adiciona marador ao mapa
            $('#json map').append(marker);
        });// fim each
    });//fim do get
```

Comment: Show where you added your click handler for the aceite button. 
 e.g.:  Looking to see your code that looks something like:  `$('#aceite').click(function () { aceite.isclicked = true; })`  (Or maybe you didn't, and that's the problem.)

Comment: You can use this method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you  @UmairKhan, it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a data attribute to the button elements when they are clicked, and then check which buttons have those attributes.

```js
$(button).click(function(){
   $(this).attr("data-clicked", true)
})
```

You might want to add a specific class to the buttons when creating them to target them with a selector above, or you could generate the buttons with `createElement` and add the event with `addEventListener`.

Then you can target all clicked buttons in jquery by just finding the buttons with that attribute: `$("button[data-clicked]")`

Or to check if a button is clicked you can use `buttonElement.hasAttribute("data-clicked")`