# why addEventListener does not work to the tag textarea after a change occurs?

Tags: javascript

I create an element as a `textarea` and i want to get the event of `change`, but it never enters in the `updateDescripton` function

```
async function displayIncompleteTask(task) {
  let newCheckBox = `<div id="${"t"+task._id}"><label for="${task._id}" class="container"><input type="checkbox" name="task" id="${task._id}" onclick = taskCompleted(this.id)><span class="checkmark"></span></label><textarea for="${task._id}" id = "${"i" + task._id}" onchange="updateTask(this.id,this.value)">${task.text}</textarea><button id="${"d" + task._id}" class="descriptionButtons" onclick="displayDescription(this.id)"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>  <div id = "${"div-" + task._id}" class="descriptionTextArea"></div></div>`

  document.getElementById("to-do").innerHTML += newCheckBox

  let taskDiv = document.getElementById("div-" + task._id)
  taskDiv.style.display= "none"

  let descriptionTag = document.createElement("textarea")
  descriptionTag.setAttribute("id", "dscp" + task._id)
  descriptionTag.setAttribute("class", "descriptionTextArea")
  descriptionTag.setAttribute("placeholder","Enter your task's description")
  taskDiv.appendChild(descriptionTag)  

  let tag = document.getElementById("dscp" + task._id)
  tag.addEventListener("change", updateDescription)
}
```

The updateDescription:

```
function updateDescription(){
  console.log("Updating")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach event to dynamic elements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: This element does not appear to have been inserted into your document so how can you do anything with it?

Comment: @palaѕн doesn't look like a good duplicate

Comment: Just tried that, i added this new line before addEventListener taskDiv.appendChild(descriptionTag) and then used getElementById to get the textarea tag and add the event listener.

Comment: What are you doing to test this? To trigger a _change_ event on a text input, you need to type something then unfocus the element (ie click out of it)

Comment: @palaѕн i saw this question, it is a more cleaner way to do it, but not the way i implemented.

Comment: @Phil yes, i want to get the information after all the changes are made. This tag should receive a description of a task and then update my database. To test it, i simply put a console.log message in the function.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. Could you please read it again and answer the question? Even better would be to edit your question and provide a runnable Stack Snippet demo of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defined `updateDescription` function,

also dont forget to add textarea to body with `document.body.appendChild(descriptionTag)`

```
let descriptionTag = document.createElement("textarea")
  descriptionTag.setAttribute("id", "dscp" + "task._id")
  descriptionTag.setAttribute("class", "descriptionTextArea")
  descriptionTag.setAttribute("placeholder","Enter your task's description")
  descriptionTag.addEventListener("change", updateDescription)
  document.body.appendChild(descriptionTag);
  function updateDescription(){
    console.log(this.value );
  }
```

```js
let descriptionTag = document.createElement("textarea")
  descriptionTag.setAttribute("id", "dscp" + "task._id")
  descriptionTag.setAttribute("class", "descriptionTextArea")
  descriptionTag.setAttribute("placeholder","Enter your task's description")
  descriptionTag.addEventListener("change", updateDescription)
  document.body.appendChild(descriptionTag);
  function updateDescription(){
    console.log(this.value );
  }
```

```css
textarea{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1>test change event</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

since it is a text field, instead of you `change` you can use `Eventlistener` and bind that with `input` event, so obviously when the user interacts with the text area, the function will be triggered.

```
descriptionTag.addEventListener("input", function(event) {});
```

But make sure `descriptionTag` is a `textarea` element.

Comment: Pretty sure it can't be anything other than a `<textarea>` given OP's first line of code