# Javascript: Issue with hiding a section

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

**Background**

If users have the item called `Get All X` in their cart, then I want to hide the upsell section called `wcf-bump-order-content`.

What I have tried

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var you1 = document.getElementsByClassName("product-name");
  var you5 = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < you1.length; i++) {
    var you2 = you1[i].textContent;
    var you3 = you2.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var you4 = you3.replace("Xs", "");
    you5 += you4;
  }
  var you6 = you5.includes("GetAllX");
  if (you6 = "true") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("wcf-bump-order-content")[0]
            .setAttribute("style", "display:none !important");
  }
  console.log(you6);
  console.log("finish");
});
```

Full code + HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/lindychen/14vLfcy5/

**Results**

As you can see from the JS fiddle, my code works and hides the relevant section. However, when I test this on my live website, it doesn't work (ie. the upsell section still shows). I can't figure out what's wrong especially since console log shows `you6` to be `true` and `finish` is also shown.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your page loading dynamically? In that case you will have to user it diffrently.

Comment: Did you try logging `document.getElementsByClassName("wcf-bump-order-content")[0]` to make sure it exists?

Comment: @Jimmy. Thanks. I am not sure if it is loading dynamically (I am using a Wordpress Plugin). Can you let me know the approach I should be taking if it is loading dynamically? I thought by having it such that the window is fully loaded prior to my code executing, this would mitigate dynamically loaded content. The class names do not change. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCooper Thanks Robbert. Yes, I have done that and it exists. This is an example of what happens when I console log it (https://i.imgur.com/iVVe1T6.png). However, what is very strange is that on the HTML side, there appears to be no change at all (https://i.imgur.com/EvlGfaY.png)?? In other words, the `display:none !important` isn't added as an attribute. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, it could be that the plugin is re-rendering the markup without the styles you've added manually (as would be the case with React).

Comment: @RobertCooper thanks. In this instance, is there a Javascript way around this then? Thank you.

Comment: @xojijog684: You should use event delegation approach like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues. First, you have a mistake in the conditional `if (you6 = "true")` should be `if (you6 === true)` or just `if(you6)`. The single equals vs. == or === and the string "true" vs the boolean value `true`.

The second problem I found after fixing the conditional in the jsfiddle and it stopped working. The problem was using `<td>` tags without the requisite `<table><tbody><tr>` around it was causing the query not to return a valid element list.

After fixing that, the jsfiddle was working again. https://jsfiddle.net/evrmorr/k481pyjm/14/

Comment: Thanks @EvanMorrison, I tried it and while it works on the fiddle, it does not work on my site. I think the issue is that the stuff is dynamically generated content and I need to figure out how to do this through event delegation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (you6 = "true") {
...
}
```

use

```
if (you6) {  //or if(you6 == true) or if(you6 =="true") or if (you6 === true)
...
}
```

because `you6 = "true"` is an assignment, not a comparison and it will always be considered `true` unless you assign null or empty string to you6.

For example:

```
if(x="")
{ console.log('a')} 
else 
{console.log('b')}

//will display b
```

however

```
if(x="anything other than empty string will be considered true")
{ console.log('a')} 
else 
{console.log('b')}

//will display a
```

Comment: Thanks @ShadiNamrouti, even after fixing for this it doesn't work. Think the issue is that it is dynamically generated content and I need to figure out how to do this through event delegation. Thanks.