# Click event not working with carousel using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have challanged myself to build a carousel entirely with javascript but I'm not sure why my click events aren't working. When I click next or prev, the image should change.

Can anyone please tell me what im doing wrong?

```
let area = document.getElementById("area");
/* FIRST SLIDE */
let slide = document.createElement('div');
slide.setAttribute('class','slides');
area.appendChild(slide);

let image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = "image1.jpg";
slide.appendChild(image);

/* SECOND SLIDE */
let slide2 = document.createElement('div');
slide2.setAttribute('class','slides');
area.appendChild(slide2);

let image2 = document.createElement('img');
image2.src = "image2.jpg";
slide2.appendChild(image2);


//More slides can be added here
/* PREV */
let prev = document.createElement('a');
prev.innerHTML = "PREV";
prev.setAttribute('class', 'prev');
prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
 showSlides(slideIndex += -1);
});
area.appendChild(prev);

/* NEXT */
let next = document.createElement('a');
next.innerHTML = "NEXT";
next.setAttribute('class', 'next');
next.addEventListener("click", function() {
 showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
});
area.appendChild(next);

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function showSlides(n) {
 console.log(n)
 var i;
 var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
 console.log(slides.length)
 if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}  // goes back to the first one  
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length} // goes to the last one
 for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
     slides[i].style.display = "none";  
 }
 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Comment: insert your html plss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you are appending your elements. when you are appending an element make sure to add listener to body. It's called [Event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'brnPrepend'){
          //do something
    }
});
```

also check this question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)