# addEventListener to appended element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

i want to insert div into my DOM, and in this div i have a button. so i want to create eventListener to this appended button, but i don't know how? i tried this but now work...

```
    const newMovie = document.createElement("div");
    newMovie.innerHTML = `
    <div class="movie">
          <img src=${movie.image}/>
          <div>
            <h3>${movie.name}</h3>
            <span>Rating : ${movie.rating} / ${movie.date}</span>
            <button id="deleteBtn">Delete</button>
          </div>
    </div>
    `;
    allMovies.append(newMovie);
    const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('#deleteBtn');
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const exsistMovie = newMovie.remove();
      movies.splice(exsistMovie, 1);
      updateMovies();
    });
```

but if i change `deleteBtn` to `newMovie` it will work, but i dont want to delete by clicking on movie, just delete when i click on this button..

i want to insert element to this div

```
<div class="movies"></div>
```

and its my all html code

```
    <div class="header">
      <h1 class="logo">My Project</h1>
      <h5>Add Movie</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="formm">
      <div class="form">
        <div class="err">
          <h1>Error</h1>
          <p>You Entered Wrong Value..</p>
        </div>
        <h2>Add Your Movie</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name Of Movie" id="movie" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="image URL" id="image" />
        <input type="number" placeholder="Rating" id="rating" />
        <div class="btns">
          <button id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movies"> </div>
```

Comment: Could you share us some of your html code?

Comment: i added all Html codes bro..

Comment: It seems to be a problem with adding an event to a dynamic created element, check this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry but you meant that i should write this? 
```
document.getElementById('deleteBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
   // something
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing allMovies is the div with the class "movies". So just try `allMovies.appendChild(newMovie);`

Answer (score -1):

How you defined allMovies in your javascript? What is allMovies? appendChild() is the correct method to add a child to a html element. If you want to use append(), you need to use jquery.

Comment: allMovies in JS is movies in HTML, yeah i used this and now its Worked.. thanks