# function reference in a template string html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this template string

```
const tdValue = `<td><a onclick=${me}>Show</a></td>`
```

and I have a function like this in the same file

```
function me() {
  alert('me');
}
```

I need to invoke the function when click, but I cannot invoke this function the way I defined, If I try

`<td><a onclick=${me()}>Show</a></td>`

then function get invoked immediately after the render, which is not I expected

Any solution for this?

Comment: Is your goal to use a dynamic function? Why not just call it like this `<td><a onclick="me()">Show</a></td>`  ??

Comment: `<a>` elements without `href` attributes are not *interactive elements*. They won't appear in the tab order or be announced by screen reader software as clickable. Use a `<button type="button">` instead. Apply CSS if you don't like the way that looks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template strings are a way to generate **strings**. Anything passed into `${...}` will be converted to a string.

If you want to a call a function from an `onclick` attribute then the value of that attribute needs to be a string of JS that calls the function:

```
onclick="me()"
```

… not the function itself.

Of course, this requires that the `me` variable holding the function be a global so that it is in scope for the `onclick` attribute.

---

Intrinsic event attributes have a bunch of issues surrounding the need for globals and weird things they do with scope and are best avoided.

I recommended using `addEventListener` instead.

The best way to use it depends on the wider context.

Possibly you should use `document.querySelector` to find the element in the DOM after creating a DOM from the string and then call `addEventListener` on the result.

Possibly you should call `addEventListener` on the `window` in advance and have a [delegated event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript).

Possibly you need to have some element-specific context made available to that function which you could provide by using `data-*` attributes.

```js
function me(event) {
  const el = event.target;
  if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "button") return;
  alert("Hello " + el.dataset.name);
}

window.addEventListener("click", me);

function addElement(message) {
  const html = `<button type="button" data-name="${message}">${message}</button>`;
  document.querySelector("#container").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

addElement("Alice");
addElement("Bob");
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Quentin, I think its better to add an event listener for that as it is not giving me errors like 'function not defined'

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the what happens when clicked. In this case, call the function.

```js
const tdValue = `<td><a onclick="me()">Show</a></td>`

function me() {
  alert('me');
}
```

Comment: This is inside a template string

Comment: The concept still works. You want the function called when clicked, not when the template string is created.

Comment: This leads to function not defined in eslint. so I think adding a event listener is a good approach for this. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Remove parenthesis:

```
<td><a onclick=${me}>Show</a></td>
```

Answer (score -2):

You must first add jquery to your project

````
<html>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"``
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Nothing in the question depends on jQuery. There is no need to add it.