# Why Javascript addEventlistener not working inside another addEventlistener

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML form and I want to create a CRUD operation. I can submit the form and display the user data but when I create an update button and want to have an addEventListener for the update and delete button. button clicks doesn't work.Please check the blow code the `"update"` eventlistenr doesn't work for testing I have an alert there.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var users = [];

  var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
  console.log(btn);
  var form = document.querySelector('#form');

  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var obj = {
      name: document.querySelector('#name').value,
      address: document.querySelector('#address').value,
      age: document.querySelector('#age').value,
    } //obj ends here

    users.push(obj);
    console.log(users);

    var userTable = document.querySelector('#userTable');
    var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    tbody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var tdata1 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata2 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata3 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata4 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata5 = document.createElement('td');

      var update = document.createElement("button");
      update.innerText = 'Update';
      update.id = "update" + i;
      tdata4.appendChild(update);

      console.log(update);
      update.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('update clicked');
      });

      var del = document.createElement("button");
      del.innerText = 'Delete';
      del.id = "delete" + i;
      tdata5.appendChild(del);

      tdata1.innerText = users[i].name;
      tdata2.innerText = users[i].address;
      tdata3.innerText = users[i].age;
      tdata4.innerHTML = update.outerHTML;
      tdata5.innerHTML = del.outerHTML;;

      update.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //console.log(e.target.id)
        console.log("update working");
      });

      del.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //console.log(e.target.id)
        console.log("delete working");
      });

      form.reset();
    }
    tr.appendChild(tdata1);
    tr.appendChild(tdata2);
    tr.appendChild(tdata3);
    tr.appendChild(tdata4);
    tr.appendChild(tdata5);
  }); // btn event listener ends here
} // window onload ends here
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CRUD</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>ADD USER</h3>
        <form id="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="age" type="number" name="age" min="10" max="100" placeholder="Age" required>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btn" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3>USERS</h3>
        <table id="userTable" class="table table-striped">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th colspan="3">Age</th>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @1891677 Could you please help

Comment: Are you testing in internet explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of typos, but here:

But basically I removed these lines:

```
tdata4.innerHTML = update.outerHTML;
tdata5.innerHTML = del.outerHTML;
```

And a duplicate addEventListener for the update:

```
update.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('update clicked');
});
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var users = [];

  var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
  var form = document.querySelector('#form');

  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var obj = {
      name: document.querySelector('#name').value,
      address: document.querySelector('#address').value,
      age: document.querySelector('#age').value,
    } //obj ends here

    users.push(obj);

    var userTable = document.querySelector('#userTable');
    var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    tbody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var tdata1 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata2 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata3 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata4 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata5 = document.createElement('td');

      var update = document.createElement("button");
      update.innerText = 'Update';
      update.id = "update" + i;
      tdata4.appendChild(update);

      update.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        console.log('update clicked on id ', e.target.id);
      });

      var del = document.createElement("button");
      del.innerText = 'Delete';
      del.id = "delete" + i;
      tdata5.appendChild(del);

      tdata1.innerText = users[i].name;
      tdata2.innerText = users[i].address;
      tdata3.innerText = users[i].age;

      del.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log("delete working on id ", e.target.id);
      });

      form.reset();
    }
    tr.appendChild(tdata1);
    tr.appendChild(tdata2);
    tr.appendChild(tdata3);
    tr.appendChild(tdata4);
    tr.appendChild(tdata5);
  }); // btn event listener ends here
} // window onload ends here
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CRUD</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>ADD USER</h3>
        <form id="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="age" type="number" name="age" min="10" max="100" placeholder="Age" required>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btn" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3>USERS</h3>
        <table id="userTable" class="table table-striped">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th colspan="3">Age</th>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that your element is dynamically created. You should use event delegation to handle the event.

Here is an article about event delegation [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) article

See This Old Post Solution Related To Your Doubt

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript#:~:text=If%20you%20create%20an%20element,is%20technically%20just%20a%20string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript#:%7E:text=If%20you%20create%20an%20element,is%20technically%20just%20a%20string.)