# how to select an element generated after a click on an element (callback ?)?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have made some code to fire some instructions after a click on an html element :

```
const datepicker = document.querySelector(".datepicker")
datepicker.addEventListener("click", () => {
//ajax request
}
```

The click on the element generates some more html elements through javascript (it displays a datepicker).
How can I add another Eventlistener on the newly created element `document.queryselector(".month-next")` by the previous click ?
edit : I use materialize datepicker, the "month-next" class is generated by the materialize javascript

Comment: Please show the code you are using to create the elements.

Comment: The same way. Get a reference of the element and call `.addEventListener()`. But unless these elements are newly created in the "datepicker" click handler these event handlers should only be added once when the "datepicker" is generated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach event to dynamic elements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: I have edited my question. I don't think this answers my question @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript) answers my question

The only variant here is to check for a class instead of an id.

```js
// Set an event handler using delegation
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('brnPrepend')) {
    console.log("Click!")
  }
});


// Append a dynamic element to DOM
setTimeout(function() {
  let dynamicElement = document.createElement("div")
  dynamicElement.innerText = "CLICK ME"
  dynamicElement.classList.add("brnPrepend")
  document.querySelector("body").append(dynamicElement)
}, 2000)
```

Comment: okay must be my mistake. I'll try that but i was convinced the solution was some sort of callback function. Thank you

Comment: It also could be done with a callback... But using delegation is simpler ;)

Comment: Alright i understand. Thank you very much for your answer :)