# Changing the property of HTML input field not taking place using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form that has two fields stationery type and stationery request qty. The stationery rqst qty field of the form accepts the number. The minimum number which can be entered in this field(QTY) depends upon the value of the stationery type field i.e. If the stationery type field value is 'pencil' then the minimum value property of the stationery request qty field should be 5 and if it is 'notepad' then the minimum property of the stationery request qty field should be 10. I am doing it by the given code but it's not working.it gives always the qnty for the first stationerytype
the jsfiddle is [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fta6sdm8/3/show)

```js
function random() {
                    document.querySelector('[name="stationerytype[]"]').value = ""
  
                    var a = document.getElementById('purpose').value;
                    if (a === "Meeting") {
                    var datalist = "datalist1";
                    } else if (a === "Departmental") {
                    var datalist = "datalist2";
                    }
    
                    document.querySelector('[name="stationerytype[]"]').setAttribute("list", datalist)

                    }
          
          var options = document.querySelectorAll(".option1");
            options.forEach(function(option) {
              option.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
                calculatingMinimunQuantity(option);
              });
              option.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('change', evt => {
                if (+evt.target.value < +evt.target.min) evt.target.value = evt.target.min
              });
            });
            
            function calculatingMinimunQuantity(option) {
              var minimum = 0, step1 = 0;
              var value = option.value;
              if (value === "PENCIL") {
                minimum = "5";
                step1="5";
              } else if (value === "NOTEPAD") {
                minimum = "10";
                step1="10";
              }
              //   getting the quantity input field
              option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("min", minimum);
              option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("step", step1);
              
        }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="purpose">Purpose</label>
                    <select type="text" name="purpose" id="purpose" class="form-control" onchange="random()" required />
                    <option ></option>
                    <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
                    <option value="Departmental">Departmental</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                  
        <td><input  type="text" name="stationerytype[]" id="stationerytype" class="option1 form-control" autocomplete="off"  required>
                <datalist id="datalist1" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="MEETING PEN">MEETING PEN</option>
                <option value="NOTEPAD">NOTEPAD</option>
                <option value="PLASTIC FOLDER">PLASTIC FOLDER</option>
                <option value="PENCIL">PENCIL</option>
                </datalist> 
                
                <datalist id="datalist2" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="A4 GREEN REAM">A4 GREEN REAM</option>
                <option value="A4 WHITE REAM">A4 WHITE REAM</option>
                <option value="BMO LETTER HEAD">BMO LETTER HEAD</option>
                </datalist>
          </td>
                            
                    
                            
        <td><input type="NUMBER" name="stationeryqtyrqst[]" id="stationeryqtyrqst" class="form-control" required ></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get the `nextSibling` element of `option` in the JS function, but the `nextSibling` element picked is `body` element. If you are using `td` element, then you need to properly use the `table` element for JS to work properly.

Here is the updated HTML and JS to achieve your requirement.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label for="purpose">Purpose</label>
  <select type="text" name="purpose" id="purpose" class="form-control" onchange="random()" required />
    <option ></option>
    <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
    <option value="Departmental">Departmental</option>
  </select>
</div>
                    
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>             
      <td><input  type="text" name="stationerytype[]" id="stationerytype" class="option1 form-control" autocomplete="off"  required>
        <datalist id="datalist1" >
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="MEETING PEN">MEETING PEN</option>
          <option value="NOTEPAD">NOTEPAD</option>
          <option value="PLASTIC FOLDER">PLASTIC FOLDER</option>
          <option value="PENCIL">PENCIL</option>
        </datalist> 

        <datalist id="datalist2" >
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="A4 GREEN REAM">A4 GREEN REAM</option>
          <option value="A4 WHITE REAM">A4 WHITE REAM</option>
          <option value="BMO LETTER HEAD">BMO LETTER HEAD</option>
        </datalist>
      </td>   
      <td><input type="NUMBER" name="stationeryqtyrqst[]" id="stationeryqtyrqst" class="form-control" required ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the update JS

```
function random() {
                    document.querySelector('[name="stationerytype[]"]').value = ""
  
                    var a = document.getElementById('purpose').value;
                    if (a === "Meeting") {
                    var datalist = "datalist1";
                    } else if (a === "Departmental") {
                    var datalist = "datalist2";
                    }
    
                    document.querySelector('[name="stationerytype[]"]').setAttribute("list", datalist)

                    }
          
          var options = document.querySelectorAll(".option1");
            options.forEach(function(option) {
              option.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
                calculatingMinimunQuantity(option);
              });
              option.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('change', evt => {
                if (+evt.target.value < +evt.target.min) evt.target.value = evt.target.min
              });
            });
            
            function calculatingMinimunQuantity(option) {
           
              var minimum = 0, step1 = 0;
              var value = option.value;
              if (value === "PENCIL") {
                minimum = "5";
                step1="5";
              } else if (value === "NOTEPAD") {
                minimum = "10";
                step1="10";
              }
              
              //   getting the quantity input field
              option.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.setAttribute("min", minimum);
              option.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.setAttribute("step", step1);
              
        }
```

Comment: Its working fine but in my form stationeryqtytype and stationeryqtyrqst are the array type field. Suppose there are four stationeryqtytype and stationeryqtyrqst then the minimum and step value for the first pair will remain same for the rest three whereas the the value in other stationeryqtytype is different . How can i overcome this

Comment: @kil You need to provide the sample of current output and the required output to make it more understandable what is the issue?

Comment: the jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/fta6sdm8/3/show

Comment: @kil updated fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/qosjuL58/](https://jsfiddle.net/qosjuL58/)

Comment: updated js fiddle not working it is same like my problem

Comment: I have updated the [https://jsfiddle.net/j134mygt/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/j134mygt/1/). I have added the alert in the `.option1` event handler. It is only called once and not called for the dynamic elements. That is why you could not get the requirement. Check the following [stack overflow] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript) if that solves your problem.

Comment: your updated fiddle is not working . I could not find ou from the given link .

Answer (score 0):

You're using `option.nextElementSibling` to call element with id `stationeryqtyrqst`, but it is pointing to your datalist with id `datalist1`. You should use `document.getElementById` instead, like this:

```
function calculatingMinimunQuantity(option) {

        var minimum = 0, step1 = 0;
        var value = option.value;
        if (value === "PENCIL") {
            minimum = "5";
            step1 = "5";
        } else if (value === "NOTEPAD") {
            minimum = "10";
            step1 = "10";
        }
        //   getting the quantity input field
        var stationeryqtyrqst = document.getElementById("stationeryqtyrqst");
        stationeryqtyrqst.setAttribute("min", minimum);
        stationeryqtyrqst.setAttribute("step", step1);

    }
```

Comment: Its working fine but in my form stationeryqtytype  and stationeryqtyrqst are the array type field. Suppose  there are four stationeryqtytype and stationeryqtyrqst  then the minimum and step value for the first pair will remain same for the rest three whereas the the value in other stationeryqtytype   is different . How can i overcome this

Comment: the jsfiddle is jsfiddle.net/fta6sdm8/3/show