# addEventListener not working for dynamic button

Tags: javascript, typescript, button, addeventlistener

I have a dynamically made button, i've set the id and class to try to set an addEventListener but the addEventListener is not read in the DOM but the ID and class is.

here is my code

```
 let button: HTMLButtonElement = document.createElement('button')

  button.id = "comment-button";
  button.className = "comment-button";
```

(ID & class is working)

Here is what i've tried:

```
  button.addEventListener("click", setComment);

  document.getElementById("comment-button")?.addEventListener("click", setComment);
```

Comment: What's the error in console?

Comment: This post might have your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an element from the document, you need to actually add the element you created to the document. `document.body.appendChild(button)`

Comment: The button is already added to the page