# Input tags when appended in the Dom are not getting checked on 'onclick' event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a section where users have to enter details. This section mostly has input tags (text, date, select), with the option to add additional fields if user wants too.

For example, when the section is first shown user gets option to select one date but if they want they can add multiple dates by using an "+" symbol. All these inputs have certain checks like blank inputs, old date selected etc.

The problem is whenever these extra inputs are appended they are not getting recognized or checked when the submit button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="relative h-fit flex flex-col startDateWrapper">

                    <div class="default w-full flex items-center startDateSections">
                      <div class="grow relative">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="dates" aria-autocomplete="none"
                          autocomplete="off" id="aptStartDate" title="Appointment Start Date"
                          onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')"
                          class="aptStartDate aptDates placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 lg:border-gray-300 lg:text-slate-900 bg-gray-900 lg:bg-transparent rounded-md tracking-widest aptFormInput" />

                        <label for="aptStartDate"
                          class="transition-all absolute text-gray-400 font-semibold uppercase tracking-widest text-[10px] lg:peer-placeholder-shown:text-gray-900 peer-placeholder-shown:text-indigo-600 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:!-translate-y-1/2 left-2.5 top-0 peer-placeholder-shown:uppercase peer-placeholder-shown:text-xs">
                          Start Date</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="addMoreDate addMore ml-5 cursor-pointer hidden">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor"
                          class="w-6 h-6 text-indigo-600">
                          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M12 2.25c-5.385 0-9.75 4.365-9.75 9.75s4.365 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75S17.385 2.25 12 2.25zM12.75 9a.75.75 0 00-1.5 0v2.25H9a.75.75 0 000 1.5h2.25V15a.75.75 0 001.5 0v-2.25H15a.75.75 0 000-1.5h-2.25V9z"
                            clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="additionalDates addSections grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-10" name="Appointment Start Date">
                    </div>

                  </div>
```

JS:

```
// This appends a date input tag in the section.

let inputWrapper = document.createElement( 'div' )
inputWrapper.classList.add( 'relative', 'flex', 'items-center', 'w-full' )

if ( inputType.getAttribute( 'id' ) === 'aptStartDate' )
      {
        dateCounter = dateCounter + 1
        let moreStartDate = `
         <input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="aptStartDate" aria-autocomplete="none"
                            autocomplete="off" id="aptStartDate" title="${ fieldTags[ dateCounter ] } Appointment Start Date" onfocus="(this.type='date')"
                            onfocusout="(this.type='text')"
                            class="newDates aptDates placeholder-transparent peer w-full my-5 h-12 text-xs font-semibold uppercase text-indigo-600 border border-indigo-600 lg:border-gray-300 lg:text-slate-900 bg-gray-900 lg:bg-transparent rounded-md tracking-widest aptFormInput" />
          `
        inputHolder.innerHTML = moreStartDate

inputWrapper.appendChild( inputHolder )

      }

// Click event
apt.create.onclick = () =>
{
  let allFilled = true

  // Check for empty fields.
  for ( let formInput of aptFormInput )
  {
    console.log( formInput );
    
    if ( formInput.value === '' )
    {
      let inputName = formInput.getAttribute( 'title' )
      promptMessages( `${ formInput.getAttribute( 'title' ) } cannot be blank.`, 'error' )
      formInput.classList.add( 'lg:border-rose-600', 'border-rose-600' )

      allFilled = false
    }
  }
}
```

I tried by adding a separate click event on appended inputs that works but that seem inefficient way to do.

Was wondering can this be done with a single click event which seem more organized as the whole section has lots of input fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach event to dynamic elements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: I did check this answer before hand and tried the suggestion but it doesn't seem to work in my case.