# How to make the Back button revert to previous HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript to generate HTML for Login and Register forms and create a Back button to make you return to the Login and Register options and make the forms disappear. The register and login forms show up when I click the buttons but I can't make the Back button work. I tried to make it regenerate the initial HTML for the page:

```js
const buttonsHTML = `
  <button class="loginOptions js-login">Log in</button>
  <button class="loginOptions js-register">Register</button>
`;

document.querySelector('.js-userOptions').innerHTML = buttonsHTML;

const inputRegisterHTML = `
  <div class="registerDisp">
    <div class="registerInput">
      <input class="input" type="username" placeholder="username">
      </input>
      <input class="input" type="e-mail" placeholder="e-mail">
      </input>
      <input class="input" type="firstName" placeholder="first name">
      </input>
      <input class="input" type="lastName" placeholder="last name">
      </input>
      <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="password">
      </input>
      <input class="input" type="passwordRepeat" placeholder="repeat password">
      </input>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <button class="backButton js-register">Register</button>
      <button class="backButton js-back">Back</button>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

function generateRegisterHTML() {
  document.querySelector('.js-userOptions').innerHTML = inputRegisterHTML;
}

document.querySelector('.js-register').addEventListener('click', generateRegisterHTML);

document.querySelector('.js-back').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.js-userOptions').innerHTML = buttonsHTML;
});
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="userOptions js-userOptions">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Research the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API), specifically `pushState()` and `popState()`

Comment: `document.querySelector('.js-back')` you are trying to access an element that doesn't event exist yet. So let's say you move that `addEventListener` function inside the `generateRegisterHTML` it will work but your register button will lose its eventListener becuz you only added that event to the button on page load. So if you press your back button. Then register won't do anything else after that

Comment: Use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34896106/215552) to attach the event handlers rather than trying to time things correctly.

Comment: The `<input/>` tag is self-closable.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl `input` is a [void element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element), which means, it is required to *not* have a closing tag. However, self-closing tags do not exist in HTML, so `<input />` is not correct either.

Comment: @HereticMonkey although the compiler ignores the slash for void elements, I still feel like the explicit slash is more readable. I don't understand why the slash matters, when OP used an `<input>` as a non-void element in the first place. This is just bike-shedding.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few issues with your code:

1. You are trying to access an element that doesn't exist yet, so this line here is gonna give you an error `document.querySelector('.js-back')`. So I moved that line inside the `generateRegisterHTML` function.
2. You are adding an eventListener to your register button only once on page load `document.querySelector('.js-register').addEventListener('click', generateRegisterHTML);` which means that if you press `register` once it will work, but if you press `back` after that, then it your register button will lose its event and it won't work anymore so you have to add the event again

```js
const buttonsHTML = `
<button class="loginOptions js-login">Log in</button>
<button class="loginOptions js-register">Register</button>
`;

function registerEventListener() {
  document.querySelector('.js-register').addEventListener('click', generateRegisterHTML);
}

document.querySelector('.js-userOptions').innerHTML = buttonsHTML;
registerEventListener();

const inputRegisterHTML = `
<div class="registerDisp">
  <div class="registerInput">
    <input class="input" type="username" placeholder = "username">
    <input class="input" type="e-mail" placeholder = "e-mail">
    <input class="input" type="firstName" placeholder = "first name">
    <input class="input" type="lastName" placeholder = "last name">
    <input class="input" type="password" placeholder = "password">
    <input class="input" type="passwordRepeat" placeholder = "repeat password">
  </div>
<div class="back">
  <button class="backButton js-register">Register</button>
  <button class="backButton js-back">Back</button>
</div>
</div>  
`;


function generateRegisterHTML() {
  document.querySelector('.js-userOptions').innerHTML = inputRegisterHTML;
  document.querySelector('.js-back').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.js-userOptions').innerHTML = buttonsHTML;
    registerEventListener();
  });

}
```

```html
<main>
   <div class="userOptions js-userOptions">
   </div>
 </main>
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it cleaned up the invalid HTML (`</input>`) injected via JavaScript.

Comment: my bad, I guess I just didn't pay attention to the HTML part inserted via js. edited my answer