Behavior of JavaScript in passing data
when i pass data as a parameter to a function which is gotten by a request and perform nullish coalescing on it does not work, if i want to check its empty then dont assign it to a variable assign another thing to a variable. but when i get that data by sending another request by passing a id it works as i want.
example:
function getQ(CatID) {
        CtID = CatID
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '<?php echo base_url('Main/getQ') ?>?ID=' + CatID);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() {
                let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                renderQuestions(response);
            }
        };
    }
function renderQuestions(response) {
        let html = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            let auditDate = response[i].AuditDate;
            if (auditDate == '' || auditDate == null) {
                let newTime = new clock()
                auditDate = newTime.getCurrentTime();
            } else {
                auditDate = response[i].AuditDate.split(" ")[0];
            }
            html += `
                                <tr class="tablerows">
<td><button class="btn btn-icon btn-primary" onclick = "openmodal('${response[i].BeforeInspectedDate}')">CAP</button></td>

                                </tr>
                            `;
        }
this does not work if empty it does not assign the value gotten by class it only assigns if value existed.
function openmodal(BeforeInspectedDate) {
        let beforedate = document.getElementById('bdate')
        const newtime = new clock()
// i have tried other conditions as well they dont work. like nullish coalescing etc.
        if (!BeforeInspectedDate) {
            beforedate.value = newtime.getCurrentTime();
        } else {
            let newbeforedate = BeforeInspectedDate.split(' ')[0]
            beforedate.value = newafterdate;
        }
    }


this works:
<td><button class="btn btn-icon btn-primary" onclick = "openmodal(${response[i].AuditDetailID})">CAP</button></td>
function openmodal(id) {
        // AJAX request to get status
        $.get("<?php echo base_url('Main/getStatus'); ?>", {
                id: id
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    const newtime = new clock()
                    if(data[0].BeforeInspectedDate != null){
                        BeforeInspectedDate = data[0].BeforeInspectedDate.split(' ')[0]
                    }
                    else{
                        BeforeInspectedDate = newtime.getCurrentTime();
                    }
                    document.getElementById('bdate').value =  BeforeInspectedDate
                    console.log(document.getElementById('bdate').value)
                }
            })
    };


Please make a [mcve] with an example of your object. We do not need to see your AJAX if it works. If it does not work, then the script parsing it will also not work. It is not clear which part of your code you have trouble with since you first describe passing data to the function, is that passing CatIP or passing response?

ALso call send AFTER assigning the onload or use chained fetch. Why mix $.get and XMLHttpRequest? You can even do $.getJSON

it could be that you may not be assigning the event handlers correctly? I tried rewriting your logic with a dummy API call and added onClicks for each button. Certainly not the most optimized approach but you can refactor it further:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div>
    <table id="mainTable"></table>
  </div>
  <script>
    window.onload = (event) => {
      function getQ(CatID) {
        CtID = CatID
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://dummy-json.mock.beeceptor.com/posts');
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function () {
          let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          renderQuestions(response);
        }
      };

      function renderQuestions(response) {
        let html = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          let title = response[i].title;
          let auditDate = ''
          if (title) {
            let newTime = new Date();
            auditDate = newTime.getTime();
          } else {
            auditDate = response[i].comment_count;
          }
          document.getElementById('mainTable').innerHTML += `
              <tr class="tablerows">
                  <td>
                    <button id="btn${i}" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary">
                      ${auditDate}${response[i].title} CAP
                    </button>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            `;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          document.getElementById('btn' + i).addEventListener('click', () => {
            let BeforeInspectedDate = new Date() + response[i].title;
            console.log('>>> BeforeInspectedDate', BeforeInspectedDate)
            let beforedate = document.getElementById('bdate')
            const newtime = new Date();
            // i have tried other conditions as well they dont work. like nullish coalescing etc.
            if (!BeforeInspectedDate) {
              beforedate.value = newtime.getCurrentTime();
            } else {
              let newbeforedate = BeforeInspectedDate.split(' ')[0]
              //beforedate.value = newafterdate;
            }
          });
        }
      }
      getQ(1);
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>



Explanation:

The code assigns a new id to each button
it then adds event listeners for each button with custom data

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34896325/6281489

I would also assign the onload before calling send.
