# Uncheck active Angular Material toggle buttons on click

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I need to modify the functionality of the standard [Angular Material toggle button component](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview), so that clicking an active button returns the component to a state where no buttons are active. This has two steps:

- Updating the value of the toggle group
- Changing the 'checked' parameter of the clicked button to false

I've tried several approaches, e.g.

Template:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup">
    <mat-button-toggle #no_btn value="no" (click)="update_toggle(group,no_btn)">No</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle #yes_btn value="yes" (click)="update_toggle(group,yes_btn)">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

JS:

```
update_toggle(group,button){
    if(group.value==""){
        group.value = button.value;
    }
    else
    {
        group.value = "";
    }
button.checked=!button.checked;
}
```

But this doesn't update the 'checked' value of the buttons, I guess because the group value set by update_toggle() is in conflict with the user action of clicking the button.

The only approach which has worked is:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup">
    <mat-button-toggle #no_btn value="no" (click)="update_toggle(group,no_btn)" (click)="group.value=='no' ? checked=false : checked=false">No</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle #yes_btn value="yes" (click)="update_toggle(group,yes_btn)" (click)="group.value=='yes' ? checked=false : checked=false">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

But two click events on a single button feels very hacky, especially as the ternary in the second click is opposite to what it instinctively should be.

Any suggestions for a better approach?

I've tried:

```
@ViewChildren('no_btn') no_btn: ElementRef;
```

and then:

```
this.no_btn['_results'][k]['_inputElement']['nativeElement']['checked']=false;
```

But the result doesn't seem to be any different from passing the button reference in the function; clicking the button a second time doesn't uncheck it. Disabling **does** work, so I think my code is correct:

```
this.no_btn['_results'][k]['_inputElement']['nativeElement']['disabled']=true;
```

Comment: why not use `@ViewChild()`'s to get the instance of the checkbox and change it that way?

Comment: Have tried this - will update question.

Comment: Wouldn't that change the value of the button itself, rather than whether or not it's checked? Or do you mean the value of the group, rather than the individual button?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A simple generic solution that doesn't require resorting to events on each button or click events at all, and doesn't require ViewChildren or hard-coding value checks,  is to use the button toggle in multiple mode and manage selections through the group change event. The change event gives you all you need so there is no need to access child components directly:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group multiple (change)="toggleChange($event)">
    <mat-button-toggle value="no">No</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="yes">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>

toggleChange(event) {
    const toggle = event.source;
    if (toggle && event.value.some(item => item == toggle.value)) {
        toggle.buttonToggleGroup.value = [toggle.value];
    }
}
```

Here it is on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjn6ga).

Comment: Great solution - thanks @gtranter. If anyone finds this is not working, you may need to update Angular Material, in my case from 5.2.2 to 6.4.1.

Comment: what if you want to uncheck all of them in function that has no $event.source ?

Comment: The example supports unchecking all options when there is no event source.

Comment: Still works perfectly fine in 2023 with Angular Material v15!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution. Note that the `change` event occurs before the `click` event.

**Component**

```
toggleChanged: boolean;

onChange() {
  this.toggleChanged = true;
}

onClick(group: MatButtonToggleGroup) {
  if (!this.toggleChanged) group.value = null;
  this.toggleChanged = false;
}
```

**Template**

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [(value)]="myValue" #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
    (change)="onChange()" (click)="onClick(group)">
    <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.value">
        {{ item.name }}
    </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Comment: Will the `change` event always occur before the `click` event, or is it like that because of the Angular implementation? In any case, from what I was able to test, your solution works well!

Answer (score 1):

According to source code (^6.4.1) the `change` event (of `MatButtonToggle`) fires at the mouse click always:

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/6.4.7/src/lib/button-toggle/button-toggle.ts#L461

We can subscribe to all toggle buttons (or only those buttons that we want to make uncheked):

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup">
    <mat-button-toggle value="no" (change)="onChange($event, group)">No</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="yes" (change)="onChange($event, group)">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

And we can add a simple handler for these events and a field that stores the state:

```
private _activeValue = "";

onChange(event, group) {
  if (this._activeValue === event.value) {
    // make unchecked
    group.value = "";
    this._activeValue = "";
  } else {
    this._activeValue = event.value;
  }
}
```

[This example is on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjn6ga-grca9y)

**Another implementation:**

We can bind the `value`.

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [value]="_activeValue">
    <mat-button-toggle value="no" (change)="onChange($event)">No</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="yes" (change)="onChange($event)">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>

public _activeValue = "";
onChange(event, group) {
   if (this._activeValue === event.value) {
       // make unchecked
       this._activeValue = "";
    } else {
       this._activeValue = event.value;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple directive based on [@Scott VandenToorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65795178/12292636):

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-button-toggle-group[appClickOnSelectedButton]',
})
export class ClickOnSelectedButtonDirective {
  @Output() appClickOnSelectedButton = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();

  private toggleChanged: boolean = false;

  @HostListener('change', ['$event'])
  onChange(): void {
    this.toggleChanged = true;
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event: PointerEvent): void {
    if (!this.toggleChanged) {
      const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
      const hasClass = hasAncestorTheClass(target, 'mat-button-toggle-checked');
      if (hasClass) {
        this.appClickOnSelectedButton.emit(event);
      }
    }
    this.toggleChanged = false;
  }
}
```

with `hasAncestorTheClass` based on [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16863971/12292636), in case of the user clicks between two options.

Usage:

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group
  [value]="form.value"
  (appClickOnSelectedButton)="onChange(null)"
  (change)="onChange($event.value)"
>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="false">No</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="true">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```