# How to unselect an Angular Material list-option in a selection-list with single selection?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular-material

I am a beginner in Angular/Angular Material and I have the following problem. I have a template with a selection-list with single selection and a few options:

```html
<mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">
  <mat-list-option>Option 1</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option>Option 2</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option>Option 3</mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

The normal behavior of that list is that an option is selected when you click on it, and only one option can be selected at a time.
However, I would like to add the behavior that the option be "unselected" when you click on it again (as it is presented in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/list/examples)).
I have fiddled around with `MatSelectionList`, `MatSelectionListChange`, and `@ViewChild()`, trying to emulate the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282112/uncheck-active-angular-material-toggle-buttons-on-click) and [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3pfu2-6n5cnt), but to no avail so far.
My question is then whether it is doable for these components? (And any solution would be very welcome of course :)) Or is it not worth trying to change the behavior of the componenents, and maybe rather start from scratch, or try bootstrap?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the Angular Material doc (https://material.angular.io/components/list/api), mat-list-option has the selected property.

So you could play with it. When an option is click (you can add a event on each option to catch the event) then you change the selected property.

Ex :

```js
const options = [{
    label: 'Option 1',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    label: 'Option 2',
    selected: false
  }
]

optionWasClicked(optionClicked) {
  this.options.forEach((option) => option.selected = (optionClicked == option) ? true : false)
}
```

```html
<mat-selection-list *ngFor="let option of options" [multiple]="false">
  <mat-list-option (click)="optionWasClicked(option)">{{ option.label }}</mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! that was clear and easy :)