# Unselect option in single answer mat-button-toggle-group

Tags: javascript, angular

my question is how can I unselect option after another click on the same option while using mat-button-toggle-group

https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncheck active Angular Material toggle buttons on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282112/uncheck-active-angular-material-toggle-buttons-on-click)