# css selector :last-child and :not

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm hoping to use CSS selectors to select the last file in the last non-hidden dir, which is `6`, with the following Javascript code:

```
const root = document.querySelector('#root');
const last = root.querySelector('.dir:not(.hidden):last-child .file:last-child');
console.log(last.innerHTML);
```

But the result is `3`. I wonder if there's any way to get `6` with only CSS selectors as opposed to recursive Javascript code.

HTML:

```
<div id='root'>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>1</div>
      <div class='file'>2</div>
      <div class='file'>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>4</div>
      <div class='file'>5</div>
      <div class='file'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='dir hidden'>
        <div class='dir'>
          <div class='file'>7</div>
          <div class='file'>8</div>
          <div class='file'>9</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/moyagivopi/1/edit?html,js,console

https://jsbin.com/huteqabiga/1/edit?html,js,console

https://jsbin.com/vosereyime/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: You're essentially looking for an `nth-child-of-selector()` function, which doesn't exist in CSS.

Comment: @Utkanos I found if I reduce the dir level to 1, and not considering the `:not(.hidden)`. I actually could get `9`. So I wonder recursive JS code is inevitable.

Comment: @Utkanos: The problem is a little deeper than that. They want the last `.file` descendant of `#root` that does not match `#root .dir.hidden .file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split you selection in 2 steps, first you get the elements without `.hidden` then you select the last one inside the *last one*. I don't think you will have a chance with pure CSS

```js
var last = document.querySelectorAll('#root > .dir:not(.hidden) > .dir:not(.hidden)');

var element = last[last.length - 1].querySelector('.file:last-child');

console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id='root'>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>1</div>
      <div class='file'>2</div>
      <div class='file'>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>4</div>
      <div class='file'>5</div>
      <div class='file'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir hidden'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>7</div>
      <div class='file'>8</div>
      <div class='file'>9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another example:

```js
var last = document.querySelectorAll('#root > .dir:not(.hidden) > .dir:not(.hidden)');

var element = last[last.length - 1].querySelector('.file:last-child');

console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id='root'>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>1</div>
      <div class='file'>2</div>
      <div class='file'>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>4</div>
      <div class='file'>5</div>
      <div class='file'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir hidden'>
      <div class='file'>7</div>
      <div class='file'>8</div>
      <div class='file'>9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another idea would be to select all the last `.file` then run a test from the last one to see if there is an ancestor with `.hidden` class. Unlike the previous solution this will work with any nesting level.

```js
//got from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16863971/8620333
function hasSomeParentTheClass(element, classname) {
  if (element.classList.contains(classname)) return true;
  return element.parentElement && hasSomeParentTheClass(element.parentElement, classname);
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.file');
var i = elements.length - 1;
for (; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (!hasSomeParentTheClass(elements[i], 'hidden')) {
    break;
  }
}

console.log(elements[i].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id='root'>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>1</div>
      <div class='file'>2</div>
      <div class='file'>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>4</div>
      <div class='file'>5</div>
      <div class='file'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir '>
    <div class='file'>10</div>
      <div class='dir hidden'>
        <div class='file'>7</div>
        <div class='file'>8</div>
        <div class='file'>9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edited by OP: removed `:last-child`, in case file 10 exists.

Comment: Thanks! It works in my example. But I get `9` when I move the `hidden` class one level down. Is there any way I still get `6` in this case?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen Ah, you want to consider nested levels?

Comment: Yes, the selectors seem to work well when there is only one level of dir.

Comment: thanks, it works in the specific example, but if I added more levels of dir, I still got `9`. https://jsbin.com/mizaqobiza/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @ElgsQianChen well, if you add more level we need to keep editing :) as you can see the selector the logic will be the same we simply add more `> .dir:not(.hidden)`

Comment: @ElgsQianChen I will edit with a more generic way that consider any level ;)

Comment: What is the levels of dir will be dynamic?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen check the update, I added an example with dynamic level

Answer (score 1):

You could use `querySelectorAll` and then slice to get the last element in the array.

See below.

```js
const root = document.querySelector('#root');
const last = Array.prototype.slice.call(root.querySelectorAll('.dir:not(.hidden):first-child > .file:last-child')).slice(-1)[0];
console.log(last.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id='root'>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>1</div>
      <div class='file'>2</div>
      <div class='file'>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>4</div>
      <div class='file'>5</div>
      <div class='file'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir hidden'>
      <div class='file'>7</div>
      <div class='file'>8</div>
      <div class='file'>9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I updated my question, in that the level of dirs will be dynamic.

Comment: I see, use Jquery instead then. Its the best solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use recursion to check all the parent nodes for the hidden class.  I have upload two snippets, one for each of your use cases.  Same JS for both.

For Reference:
https://codeburst.io/learn-and-understand-recursion-in-javascript-b588218e87ea

```js
const root = document.querySelector('#root');
const files = root.querySelectorAll('.file');
var div;

for (var i=0; i< files.length; i++){
  if (!doesParentContainClass(files[i])) {
    div = files[i]; 
  }
}

console.log(div.innerHTML)

function doesParentContainClass(element) {
    if (element.className && element.className.split(' ').indexOf('hidden')>=0) return true;
    return element.parentNode && doesParentContainClass(element.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<div id='root'>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>1</div>
      <div class='file'>2</div>
      <div class='file'>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>4</div>
      <div class='file'>5</div>
      <div class='file'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir hidden'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>7</div>
      <div class='file'>8</div>
      <div class='file'>9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
const root = document.querySelector('#root');
const files = root.querySelectorAll('.file');
var div;

for (var i=0; i< files.length; i++){
  if (!doesParentContainClass(files[i])) {
    div = files[i]; 
  }
}

console.log(div.innerHTML)

function doesParentContainClass(element) {
    if (element.className && element.className.split(' ').indexOf('hidden')>=0) return true;
    return element.parentNode && doesParentContainClass(element.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<div id='root'>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>1</div>
      <div class='file'>2</div>
      <div class='file'>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='file'>4</div>
      <div class='file'>5</div>
      <div class='file'>6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='dir'>
    <div class='dir'>
      <div class='dir hidden'>
        <div class='dir'>
          <div class='file'>7</div>
          <div class='file'>8</div>
          <div class='file'>9</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```